# SQL Server denormalization question - store user data in 1,3, or 21 tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, ddl, denormalization, sql-server-performance

A section of our web site calls for asking the user 20 multiple-choice questions about themselves (a "profile").  This part of the web site will be frequently viewed, and occasionally updated.  The web site is expected to develop a high amount of traffic, so some consideration is being given to try and prepare for performance issues.

The 3 ways I can see to store this in the DB are:

1. Create 1 table for each question, each table has QuestionID and Answer, then a CustomerInfo table to store the profile data, with foreign keys mapped to the questions.
2. Question, Question_Type, and Answers tables.  Stuff everything into these constructs.  My concern here is in particular the 20 or so inserts required to update a profile.  Is this going to be a performance hit at high traffic volumes?
3. Denormalized single table, one field per question, hard-code the answer codes in the HTML and/or in a C# object.

I'm leaning towards #2 or #3.  What do you think would be the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create the following tables:

```
Survey (PK:SurveyID)
Question (PK:QuestionID, FK:SurveyID)
QuestionAnswer (PK:QuestionAnswerID, FK:QuestionID)
QuestionResponse (PK:QuestionResponseID, FK:QuestionAnswerID, FK:UserID)
```

You can minimize the load by doing the inserts in one statement, e.g.:

```
insert into QuestionResponse
(QuestionAnswerID, UserID)
select 23, 3
union all
select 72, 3
union all
select 488, 3
```